# Export/Save jLabel contents to new folder

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, save, jlabel

I have a program that perform two functions: Upload image, Export image.
after uploading an image it will shown in a jLabel,

- my question : is there any way to save this image and export it to a new folder on desktop or any place the user choose?
- for example, if I uploaded an image and its displayed on jLabel, when I press the Export button the program should open a dialog window asks me to choose a name for a folder and save the image in it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By 'upload' (which to me generally implies sending something to a remote location such as a web site) or 'load' (as in load something from the client machine into your app.)?

Answer (score 1):

It sure is possible!

Take a look a JFileChooser, ImageIcon, and ImageIO and specifically search around for tutorials on using ImageIO